# Is NSArrayController deprecated, what is its replacement?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I found an Xcode project that uses something called an `NSArrayController` like this

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyDocument : NSPersistentDocument {

    IBOutlet NSArrayController *itemsArrayController;
    NSArray *_sortDescriptors;
    IBOutlet NSTableView *itemsTableView;

}
```

I was trying to use the project, which implements drag and drop, as a guide for an app I'm currently building. There's nothing in Xcode documentation when I option click on `NSArrayController` and I tried to create an `NSArrayController` property but received a warning that it doesn't exist. Was it deprecated? What has its functionality been replaced by?

Comment: Next question: What the heck is an `NSTableView`?

Comment: Surely it would be this first: What the heck is NSPersistentDocument? Better yet, I find puzzling that the import is not already complaining, seeing as on iOS there is no Cocoa/Cocoa.h.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSArrayController is part of the AppKit.framework which is only available on the MacOS platform.

Comment: And so it `NSTableView`.